# Thread associated with transaction suspended for a long time in JBoss 6.1.0

Tags: java, multithreading, transactions, jboss6.x

I am facing a big concern in `JBoss 6.1.0`. It is a multi threaded application and am using stateless EJB with BMT and Sybase DB. JDK used is `1.7.76u`. User transaction is started. Queries got ran but the associated thread tries to commit after ONE HOUR. I am not aware what happened to the thread executing. It is suspended for sure but not from the code.

Can anyone please give a valuable pointer about why the thread got suspended for more than hour. Obviously after an hour, thread resuming and trying either COMMIT or ROLLBACK will fail and has failed as the default transaction timeout is 300 seconds (which is JBoss 6 default value).

```
2017-01-09 10:01:49,389 DEBUG [TestDAO] [EventId: ] [pool-63-thread-6] SQL SELECT QUERY
2017-01-09 10:01:49,391 DEBUG [TestDAO] [EventId: ] [pool-63-thread-6] ['dao.rowsProcessed']: 1 rows processed
2017-01-09 10:01:49,389 DEBUG [TestDAO] [EventId: ] [pool-63-thread-6] SQL UPDATE QUERY
2017-01-09 10:01:49,391 DEBUG [TestDAO] [EventId: ] [pool-63-thread-6] ['dao.rowsUpdated']: 1 row updated
2017-01-09 11:05:48,213 DEBUG [DAOUtils] [EventId: ] [pool-63-thread-6] commitTx
2017-01-09 11:05:48,214 ERROR [DAOUtils] [EventId: ] [pool-63-thread-6] commitTx() ARJUNA-16063 The transaction is not active!
2017-01-09 11:05:48,215 DEBUG [DAOUtils] [EventId: ] [pool-63-thread-6] rollbackTx
2017-01-09 11:05:48,215 ERROR [DAOUtils] [EventId: ] [pool-63-thread-6] rollbackTx() java.lang.IllegalStateException - BaseTransaction.rollback - ARJUNA-16074 no transaction!
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have long running transactions which is being time-out.

"The transaction is not active!" are caused by a transaction timeout.  When a transaction times out the transaction manager rolls it back asynchronously and then when a compontent tries to access the transaction again (e.g. to commit it or roll it back) it won't be able to according to the JTA spec.

The default transaction timeout has been defined under "default-timeout" attribute at "transactions" subsystem in the application server configuration.

- The default is 300 seconds / 5 minutes.
- You may modify the value to increase the default transaction timeout.
- You may set the value to 0 to disable the transaction reaper/ transaction timeout.

The application server VM must be restarted for the default-timeout change to be applied.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.4">
    <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>  <!-- HERE -->
</subsystem>
```

It looks to me like your it is taking longer than 5 minutes to process the message therefore its transaction is timing out.

I would recommend you to increase the transaction timeout to a higher figure to avoid this situation. It would be good if you could refactor the application code to reduce the time taken to complete a transaction. So it may be that the application logic is correctly handling the scenario in this case

Comment: Many thanks for the response.. Anup. Hope you have answered me in JBoss Developer site as well. I have replied you with the description of the problem in detail. https://developer.jboss.org/thread/273677  this is a very very sporadic problem and I strongly suspect this could be related to any environment or runtime issues of JBoss. Any hints from you will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the JBoss forum, this is not issue with the transaction timeout.
There is no point in extending the timeout for transaction as this blocks all the other applications because locks in the database is held by transaction.

Threads executing the transaction are frozen. Any hints on why this thread is blocked from committing would be of great help.

Rgds
Manohar